# Delphi-XE5 Android Development. What is the best way to free non-modal forms?

Tags: android, delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe5

In Delphi for windows there is no problem to Free (Form.free) closed secondary dynamicaly-created form because where is "ShowModal" method. But Delphi for Android does not support Form.ShowModal, and we have to use Show method. But I figured out what when I  close (Form.close) secondary form it is still in memory and even run code Onresize event (???). What is the best way to Free forms in non-Modal call?

In another words: How do I close a form from an OnClick event handler on that form, and ensure that the form's destructor runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

See important note below.

---

In XE5 for Android there is a possibility to show a form with modal results, an overloaded `ShowModal` procedure using an anonymous method:

> procedure ShowModal(const ResultProc: TProc); overload;

You can find it described in this article by Marco Cantu, [`Delphi XE5 Anonymous ShowModal and Android`](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/xe5_anonymous_showmodal_android.html).

Here is the example how to use this procedure:

```
var
  dlg: TForm1;
begin
  dlg := TForm1.Create(nil);
  // select current value, if avaialble in the list
  dlg.ListBox1.ItemIndex := dlg.ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(Edit1.Text);
  dlg.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      if ModalResult = mrOK then
      // if OK was pressed and an item is selected, pick it
        if dlg.ListBox1.ItemIndex >= 0 then
          edit1.Text := dlg.ListBox1.Items [dlg.ListBox1.ItemIndex];
      dlg.DisposeOf;  // Wrong !!!, see note below
    end);
```

*Note that the **`dlg.DisposeOf;`** will force the form to be destroyed, overriding the ARC automatic handling.*

You can also find a description in the documentation, [`Using Modal Dialog Boxes in Mobile Apps`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Using_Modal_Dialog_Boxes_in_Mobile_Apps) and here, [`ShowModal Dialogs in FireMonkey Mobile Apps`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/ShowModal_Dialogs_in_FireMonkey_Mobile_Apps).

---

As found by others, http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1585, calling `DisposeOf` inside the anonymous method is wrong because the anonymous frame must be able to handle ModalResult from a valid object. Use this pattern instead to free the modal dialog, [Freeing Your Modal Dialog Box](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/ShowModal_Dialogs_in_Mobile_Platforms).

```
procedure TModalForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

Comment: It would be nice to know how to do it with Show

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, at some point a call to `form.DisposeOf` has to be executed. In this case the OP really wants the behavior of a modal dialog and this answer shows how to do that.

Comment: Why does DisposeOf need to be called? Assignment to nil should suffice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, assigning a nil does not cause an immediate call to the destructor.

Comment: It does if it is the only ref

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that is correct, but here we want to explicitly say we want to get rid of the form. Read doc [`TObject Construction and Destruction Methods under ARC`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers#TObject_Construction_and_Destruction_Methods_under_ARC).

Comment: Quote: `One way to look at the difference between Free and DisposeOf, is to consider the intent. When using Free, the intent is that the user needs that particular reference detached from the instance. It does not imply any kind of disposal or deallocation. By contrast, DisposeOf is the programmer's way of explicitly telling the instance that it needs to "clean itself up". It never necessarily implies deallocations, DisposeOf does an explicit "pre-clean" of the instance, which then relies on the normal reference count semantics to eventually deallocate the instance.`

Comment: Well, you can only call `DisposeOf` when there are other parties holding references, if you be sure that all other parties will respect the zombie state of the object.

Comment: A missing [weak] reference and your form will be hopelessly in limbo. That is one reason Embarcadero recommends the use of `DisposeOf` in this situation.

Comment: A reference that doesn't check for a zombie, and it's game over too.

Comment: Agree. Right now the whole ARC implementation leaks too much implementation detail (besides memory leaks), causing lots of problem in FMX and elsewhere. Hopefully it will be set straight by the time I start using it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set in the ObjectInspector

```
ModalResult = mrOK
```

or in your

```
procedure TForm1.ExitButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ModalResult := mrOK;
end;
```

for the example dlg.ShowModal above!